# Test for numeric variable when groups are probabilities

Tags: conditional-probability, biostatistics

I have an experiment where we obtained blood tests (glucose, hemoglobine, leukocytes…) of different patients who were in hospital for a certain infectious disease.

Depending on the day the patient was admitted in the hospital there is a probability that the patient had a different strain of the disease (strain A, B or C).

For example, between 1st March 2022 and 15th March the probability of strain A, B and C was 0.9, 0.05 and 0.05 respectively. So a patient admitted in that time would be probably be infected by strain A.

Given this, I would like to test if certain numeric variables (hemoglobine, leukocytes…) are different depending on the probability of having a strain.

How would you model this situation given these probabilities?

Comment: Are you doing sort of discriminant analysis? And what do you mean by "compare these blood test"?

Comment: No, the idea is not performing a LDA. I’ll clarify the question